# React.js: Find a string in a string and make it clickable if found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string, search, react-hooks

I am new to react js. I was supposed to achieve the following in my project:

- Find a defined string in a large string
- Make the defined link clickable if it is found in the large string

My code:

```
function FindWord() {
  const givenWord = "hello there click this Forgot password if you do not remember your password"
  const toSearch="Forgot password"
  return (    
    <>
      {givenWord.includes(toSearch)?
        givenWord.substring(0,givenWord.indexOf(toSearch).toString()) + `<span style={{color:'red'}}>${toSearch}</span>` + (toSearch)
      :"No"}
    </>
    
  )
}
```

Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to surround the search string with an anchor tag like so:

```
const toSearch="Forgot password"

    const target = givenWord.indexOf(toSearch);
    const firstPart = givenWord.substring(0,target);
    const secondPart = givenWord.substring(target + toSearch.length, givenWord.length)

      return (    
        <>
          {givenWord.includes(toSearch)?
            <span>{firstPart}<a href="your-url.com" style={{color:'red'}}>${toSearch}</a>{secondPart}<span/>
          :"No"}
        </>
        
      )
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple `Linkify` component/hook that accepts a string, and an object of `{ [text]: ref }`. The hook splits the string along the links, and then maps the items to normal text or links, according to the exitance of `href` in the `links` object. The component renders the `texts` with `a` for links, and `span` for normal texts.

```js
const { useMemo } = React

const useLinkify = (str, links) => useMemo(() =>
  str
    .split(new RegExp(`(${Object.keys(links).join('|')})`, 'g'))
    .map((text, id) => ({
      id,
      href: links[text],
      text
    }))
, [str, links])

const Linkify = ({ str, links }) => {
  const texts = useLinkify(str, links)

  return texts.map(({ id, href, text }) => {
    const Tag = href ? 'a' : 'span'
    
    return <Tag key={id} href={href}>{text}</Tag>
  })
}

const str = 'hello there click this Forgot password if you do not remember your password'
const links = { 'Forgot password': 'https://whatever.com' }

ReactDOM.render(
  <Linkify str={str} links={links} />,
  root
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```